# Primefaces 3.3/3.4 tabview: ajax update on tabChange

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

Using the following code, the content of the two tabs is cleared on tabChange event instead of being updated:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:tabView id="tabview">
        <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{testBean.onChange}" update="@form"/>
        <p:tab title="Tab 1">
            <h:outputText value="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet." id="ht1"/>
        </p:tab>
        <p:tab title="Tab 2">
            <h:outputText value="Donec et mi et arcu commodo hendrerit." id="ht2"/>
        </p:tab>
    </p:tabView>
</h:form>
```

The onChange method is an empty method is my test code.

I'm missing something here but I can't find what. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I'm using a ViewScoped bean.

I've tried `update="@form"`, `update=":form"` and `update=":form:tabview"`, the same problem occurs.

If I use `update="ht1, ht2"`, everything is fine **but** in my onChange method, I would like to select programmatically the tab I want to be active (there is a treatment in my real code that validates some data: if the validation fails, I'd like to stay on tab 1, if it's ok, go to tab 2). To achieve that, I guess I must update the whole tabview component and not only the tabs' content. But maybe I'm wrong?

**Full code**

I made a few changes, here's my updated code that still doesn't work.

Managed bean:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import org.primefaces.event.TabChangeEvent;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable {

    private int idx;
    private String s1 = "test 1";
    private String s2 = "test 2";

    public TestBean() {
        System.out.println("TestBean.init");
    }

    public void onChange(TabChangeEvent e){
        s1 = "TEST TEST";
        s2 = "TEST TEST";
    }

    public int getIdx() {
        return idx;
    }

    public void setIdx(int idx) {
        this.idx = idx;
    }

    public String getS1() {
        return s1;
    }

    public void setS1(String s1) {
        this.s1 = s1;
    }

    public String getS2() {
        return s2;
    }

    public void setS2(String s2) {
        this.s2 = s2;
    }
}
```

Facelet:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form id="form">
            <p:tabView id="tabview" activeIndex="#{testBean.idx}">
                <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{testBean.onChange}" update="@form"/>
                <p:tab title="Tab 1">
                    <h:outputText value="#{testBean.s1}" id="ht1"/>
                </p:tab>
                <p:tab title="Tab 2">
                    <h:outputText value="#{testBean.s2}" id="ht2"/>
                </p:tab>
            </p:tabView>
            <h:messages/>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**

I changed my Primefaces jar from 3.4 to 3.2 and magic, this behaviour doesn't happen anymore. I tried then with 3.3 and boom, error. I'm going to ask on the Primefaces forum if this is a known bug.

Comment: What are you trying to do and what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @roel Upon changing the current tab he wants to invoke some logic, pretty obvious...?

Comment: I've experienced some trouble with `update="@form"` on this kind of Primefaces objects before. You could try referencing an `id` here (not sure if it solves your problem).

Comment: @roel as Aquillo said, there is some logic in my real code that's called in the onChange method. Aquillo: I tried referencing an id but the same problem occurs. Thanks though

Comment: well, can you then tell us what logic you want to do? Maybe there is the problem?

Comment: The problem can't come from my logic as my test case doesn't use it. The sample code I wrote in my post is complete enough to see the problem I'm trying to solve. If you really need to, just think of my onChange method as ´public void onChange(TabChangeEvent e){ System.out.println("onChange"); }`.

Comment: I copy pasted your code, but it works correctly. Do you have any errors in your server log? or javascript errors? Is this code just the page, or is there more code (wich seems unrelated) in the page. Primefaces tend to give problems when using dialogs (in the wrong place of a page/form) for example

Comment: Omg, I can't believe it's ok for you and not for me. I added my full code, is there something that's different from yours? I'm using JSF 2.1.7 with Primefaces 3.3.1 on Jboss 7.0.1.Final. What is your configuration? Thanks for the help, btw.

Comment: I still can't understand why the output fields are not rendered: I can see them in Firebug's XML response: `<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" aria-expanded="false"><a href="#form:tabview:j_idt8">Tab 2</a></li></ul><div class="ui-tabs-panels"><div id="form:tabview:j_idt7" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false"><span id="form:tabview:ht1">TEST TEST</span></div>`.

Comment: I have primefaces 3.2 and tomcat 7.2

Comment: Tested with PF 3.2 and it's actually working. Edited my question.

Answer (score 6):

You should use activeIndex

```
 <p:tabView id="tabview" activeIndex="#{testBean.tabIndex}" >
```

And in your onchange method, after validation set the correct tabindex.

Comment: This is indeed the right way to set the active tab programmatically, thanks, tested and approved.

Comment: No, it's not the right way, but it was sure copied all over the Internet... Why would you bind `activeIndex`, but then manually edit its value in the `tabChange` listener? When you bind it you're already telling PrimeFaces to read/write it. Posting another answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's not enough to bind the `activeIndex` attribute. You also have to trigger an AJAX submit to update the value on the server. So it should be:

```
<p:tabView activeIndex="#{bean.index}">
    <p:ajax event="tabChange" />
</p:tabView>
```

Comment: When a tabView is not in a form, tabChange also needs partialSubmit to be enabled. See https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/695